# Safety of using DLLs as C++ game SDK release (dll modified, exe never)

Tags: c++, dll, sdk, shared-libraries

I've been trying to come up with the best way to distribute a portion of my game code, but not all of it, in order to allow people to mod the game but not create standalone games using my code. This is how many games already work, such as Doom3 - before the GPL release, the SDK was only a portion of the code that would create a DLL for the unmodifiable EXE.

I successfully split up my code into an EXE/SDK for this purpose, but my concern is that the EXE references classes in the SDK. For one example, if I compile the EXE which has an array of objects of type Entity, Entity is declared in the SDK, and then I go and add another member variable to that class, compile the DLL, and then run the old EXE with the new DLL, wouldn't that mean that the EXE has incorrect information about the size of Entity?

Or am I over-thinking this?

Comment: Use versioning of the dll and exe to ensure that they are compatible. If you make such a change to a class in the dll, you'd then increment its version number. The executable would then check against the dll version number and should fail gracefully if it is incompatible.

Comment: This doesn't work because the purpose of having a DLL in the first place is to allow others to make modifications without the full source.

Comment: What are they making modifications to - the dll, or do you mean the header files that accompany the dll?

Comment: Anything they want that is included in the SDK. Doom3 was very flexible in this way, there was a ton of code in the SDK that you could change in any way you want, but the EXE still had a whole bunch of important stuff as well, and it was seemingly almost random sometimes what things were not included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a whole heap of problems with "if you modify this class it wont work with the class defined somewhere else.

There are also plenty of solutions to those problems.

Typically forming interfaces using (smart) pointers and/or references rather than the class itself avoids both parts of the code having to agree on the size of a class.

So, for example, instead of having :

```
class EntityCollection
{
  private:
   vector <Entity> entities;
  public:
   void addEntity(Entity e) { entities.push_back(e); }
   void removeEntity(Entity e) { ... } 

};
```

we'd use a pointer style storage (should really use smart pointers, but to make it short and simple, I'm not):

```
class EntityCollection
{
  private:
   vector <Entity*> entities;
  public:
   void addEntity(Entity* e) { entities.push_back(e); }
   void removeEntity(Entity* e) { ... } 

};
```

Now, it won't matter how large the entity is, or what it contains, it will still be "pointer sized" in the vector.

Another variant is to have a "pimpl" interface. You have a main class defintion, inside it is a (smart) pointer to an implementation class, which provides a known set of virtual functions.

Something like this:

```
class Entity
{
   public:
     class EntityImpl 
     {
        virtual int func()  = 0;
        ...
     };
     Entity(EntityImpl* impl) pImpl(impl) {}
     ...
     int func() { return pImpl->func(); }
   private:
     EntityImpl* pImpl;
};
```

These are of course not your only possible concerns, but should give you some ideas of "here's something you use to solve the problem".

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was a simple answer for this example but couldn't quite put my finger on it. I'm still concerned about what kind of unforeseen problems might arise through doing this "allow users to edit the DLL but not the EXE" situation.

Comment: Aside from "badly behaved DLL will crash the executable", it's not an unknown scenario. Plugins to many commercial programs are .dll (or .so files in Linux). Since crashing will only really destroy that user's experience it's not that terrible.